# Reassigning Case Role Gives DB Constraint on Membership

Tags: drupal, civicase

I recently moved to a new webhost with Drupal 7 and upgraded to CiviCRM 5.21.0. Everything seems to be working fine, I have no errors in the Administration Console. However, when I go to cases, and I reassign a case role, I get an error:

"DB Constraint Violation - membership_contact_id should possibly be marked as mandatory for Membership,get API. If so, please raise a bug report."

I don't even have CiviMember or CiviCampaign enabled. I ran the upgrade script again, no issues. I disabled and re-enabled CiviCase again. Clear cache, deleted everything in template_c. I don't know what else to try. Any ideas?

Comment: What extensions do you have installed?

Comment: Summary Fields, Related Permissions Module, CiviRules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on chat discussion there was a missing database field for unknown reasons. Running this helped:

`ALTER TABLE civicrm_membership ADD COLUMN status_override_end_date date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Then end date of membership status override if ''Override until selected date'' override type is selected.';`